# Automatical conversion of data from float to int while saving dataframe as csv file using to_csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to save my dataframe as csv file which has two columns ID and Target. I want the target column to be float datatype i.e 1.0, 0.0 instead of 1 or 0. And I have created a dataframe of these values and my Target column is of floating type. But when I save this dataframe to csv file using to_scv() the "Target" column in the csv file is automatically converted to int datatype i.e. 1 and 0. I did the following

```py
>>> submission["Target"] = submission["Target"].astype(float)
>>> submission.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

[image]

Output csv file:

[image]

The expected output of Target column in csv file was supposed to be 1.0 or 0.0 but the actual output is 1 or 0

Answer (score 1):

`pd.to_csv` outputs the correct type. My assumption is the program you use to display the CSV file auto-formats the cell content and thus does not display the `.0`s.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'Target': 0.0}, {'id': 1, 'Target': 1.0}])
>>> fname = 'out.csv'
>>> df.to_csv(fname, index=False)
>>> with open(fname) as fh:
...     columns = fh.readline().strip().split(',')
...     rows = [dict(zip(columns, row.strip().split(','))) for row in fh.readlines()]
>>> print(rows)
[{'Target': '0.0', 'id': '0'}, {'Target': '1.0', 'id': '1'}]
```